# Burp suite is not intercepting localhost | bWAPP | Burp Suite

Tags: firefox, proxy, localhost, web-application

I am trying to get learn web application security using [bWAPP](http://www.itsecgames.com/) (A buggy web application) which is hosted using Xampp on windows machine. I have configured the proxy (`127.0.0.1:8080`) in browser properly as well as getting alerts in Burp Suite.

An *Instant Burp Suite Starter* guide suggest that one should have the exception field ...completely empty. In firefox by default there's `localhost, 127.0.0.1` values in `No Proxy For:` exception filed. When I remove the entries in order to follow the guide I am unable to access bWAPP login page `localhost/bWAPP/login.php` in browser.

If I have exceptions for localhost It works fine in browser but then Burp Suite does not pickup any traffic relating to `127.0.0.1`.

Is the whole configuration faulty or am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't write the port in Burp Suite's Target Scope host field. For example, don't write "localhost:8081". Instead, write "localhost" in the host field, and "8081" in the port field.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Type about:config in Firefox browser tab , search no_proxies_on, remove the content from value

Editing the UI 'no proxy for' field should automatically change this value, but due to some reason, UI values were not syncing with this setting. I am currently debugging the root cause

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail on why and how this works?

Comment: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.proxy.no_proxies_on

Answer (score 0):

Go to about:config and change network.proxy.allow_hijacking_localhost to true

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, you can use your router assigned IP address to intercept the traffic of apps that running on your `localhost`.

Ex. 192.168.1.156

If your app hosted on port number 80 then browse the app in browser with `http://192.168.1.156/`. Burp Suite will surely pick up and intercept the traffic from the apps hosted on your localhost.

You can get your IP address with the following command:

- For Windows: `ipconfig`
- For Linux: `ifconfig`